# why it is not throwing "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" exception

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, mdi, openform

I have a logout menu option in my MDI application. On log out I want to close all open forms. currently i am using following code snippet to achieve this;

```
For Each f As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
    If f.Name = Me.Name Then
        For Each child As Form In f.MdiChildren
            child.Close()
        Next
    Else
        f.Close()
    End If
Next
```

It is working perfect in my test environment, even though I expected ***For Each loop*** will throw "***Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute"*** exception. since on each child form Close() calls,  f.MdiChidren collection get modified, that surprised me a lot. Can anybody tell me why it's not throwing that exception?

However it throws "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" in a client system.

Comment: It sounds like the collection isn't being modified in your test environment.  The fix for live environment would be to add forms to a separate list first and loop over that list closing them.

Comment: MdiChildren returns an *array*, not a collection.  You are not close to diagnosing your user's crash.

Comment: @JonAlb: i don't think that is the case, i used break point and verified that child form collection is size getting reduce in each iteration.

Comment: @ Hans Passant: The function that throw exception contain only that much code with a try.. catch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a 64bit OS it could be related to that.  I have had issues with that in the past, the work around we had found was to set the project target to x86 (When possible).

Here is a post that has an answer that has a nice explanation of the issue I am talking about.

[VS2008 Debugger does not break on unhandled exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103034/vs2008-debugger-does-not-break-on-unhandled-exception)

I should mention I have still seen it in 2010 as well.