# Dictionary KeyNotFoundException NOT giving error ... WHY?

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary

**This question is not why it is giving an error .. rather *why it is not* giving an error ...**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dic["666bytes"] = "ME";
    MessageBox.Show(dic["should_give_error"]);
}
```

This should give an error, right ? as dic["should_give_error"] is not present but it is not giving an error (the Form loads normally). But I can trap it with *try..catch(KeyNotFoundException)* block...how come ?

Comment: Are you sure your form load event is actually hooked up?

Comment: @JonSkeet : Yes, I can do everything normally

Comment: [Why the form load can't catch exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209706/why-the-form-load-cant-catch-exception)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you aren't actually running `Form1_Load`. Here's a short but complete program to demonstrate the exception being thrown as expected:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Form form = new Form();
        form.Load += Form1_Load;
        Application.Run(form);
    }

    private static void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dic["666bytes"] = "ME";
        MessageBox.Show(dic["should_give_error"]);
    }
}
```

Compile and run that, and you get an exception dialog box.

Comment: Hi, yes I am running the right Form_Load event... I can do all other things during this event like change backcolor, show other Messagebox etc...

Comment: @666bytes: Did you try the code I gave? Because as I say, it definitely shows an exception box for me....

Answer (score 0):

You gotta read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) better. Quote:

```
// If a key does not exist, setting the indexer for that key 
// adds a new key/value pair.
openWith["doc"] = "winword.exe";
```

So, when you call `dic["should_give_error"]` the program goes, oh, that key doesn't exist, so let's create one. So it does, and returns an empty string.

Edit: Okay, it doesn't return the empty string when you try to get a non-existent key, but the load event can't throw exceptions under certain conditions. But if you leave it like it is, you should have an empty value for the key `"should_give_error"`.

Comment: thats not the case, please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I did found the answer (it's a BUG, not the answer I was expecting) and here are the references ...

1. [Reference # 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209706/why-the-form-load-cant-catch-exception)
2. [Reference # 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103034/vs2008-debugger-does-not-break-on-unhandled-exception/4354724#4354724)
3. [Reference # 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a/4934010#4934010)