# Seemingly odd behaviour in VS C# debugger

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have this code in my form_load method...

```
System.IO.StreamReader file =  new System.IO.StreamReader(serverList);
Servers = new List<Server>();
String line;
//while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
while (! file.EndOfStream)
{
    line = file.ReadLine().Trim();
    if (line[0] != '#' && line != "")
    {
        Servers.Add(new Server() { ServerName = line.Split('|')[0], 
            IPorHostname = line.Split('|')[1] });
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I don't understand what the debugger is doing!  Is this a bug?");
    }
}
```

I wanted to be able to ignore empty lines in the file I was reading from, so I added the `line != ""` bit and trimmed the line before checking it in the if statement.    When loading the application the server list would be empty.  So I switched into debug mode and step into this code.  When `line` is empty and I press F11 on the if statement, the debugging/stepping stops and the application shows. What I expect to happen is to go back around the while loop but that doesn't happen.

I added an else, with a message box as a test... The message box doesn't show!

In short, when `line` is empty neither the true nor false code is executed, and the debugger stops stepping through the code.

What's happening here?   Am I missing something obvious or is this a bug in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with the `Load` event. It is called in such a way that exceptions inside are swallowed silently.

As an example of what can go wrong in your code, this line:

```
if (line[0] != '#' && line != "")
```

will throw an exception if the `line` variable contains an empty string, since then `line[0]` is incorrect, there is no index #0 for an empty string.

However, since you're executing this in the `Load` event, such an exception is just swallowed.

To fix this, add a `try/catch` block inside the `Load` event handler, around all the code in there:

```
private void Form_Load(...)
{
    try
    {
        ... all your existing code here
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // add more specific exception handlers
    {
        ... handle the exception here
    }
}
```

Here are some other questions and answers here on Stack Overflow about this problem:

- [Why the form load can't catch exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209706/why-the-form-load-cant-catch-exception)
- [VS2008 Debugger does not break on unhandled exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103034/vs2008-debugger-does-not-break-on-unhandled-exception/4354724#4354724)

Comment: I just swapped the conditions `line != "" && line[0] != '#'` and my code worked as expected.  Your answer is correct and makes sense.  (This was baffling me) I will accept your answer in 8 minutes when it will allow me to :)

Comment: Yes, that fixes the exception, but it does not fix your other problem, that exceptions thrown in Form_Load are silently swallowed. You should add a try/catch block around that method, or preferrably, find a different event to place your code inside.

Comment: I'll add code to handle exceptions, but for now, swapping the conditions makes my app run, and more to the point I now understand what was happening.